# How to change a string input by the user into a dictionary with a key and value

Tags: python, string, dictionary, sentence

```
sentence = input ("give sentence")    
user input = HELLO I LOVE PYTHON
```

I want the sentence given to be changed into the format, with a variable `sentence_dict`

```
{1:HELLO, 2:I, 3:LOVE, 4:PYTHON}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `split()` method to get a list of the words in `sentence`:

```
words = sentence.split()
```

Then use the `enumerate` built-in function to construct a generator that associates ascending numbers with the words in the list.  By default `enumerate` starts its numbering at 0 but you want it to start at 1, so pass that value as the second argument:

```
numbered_words = enumerate(words, 1)
```

Then use the `dict` built-in function to construct a dictionary from the output of that generator.  Luckily the generator emits its (number, word) tuples in the format that matches what you're trying to build -- `dict` constructs a dictionary by using the first item in the tuple as the key, the second as the value:

```
sentence_dict = dict(numbered_words)
```

You can jam that all into one line if you want to be terse:

```
sentence_dict = dict(enumerate(sentence.split(), 1))
```

The `enumerate` generator is the only tricky part.  `enumerate` is similar to `xrange` in that it doesn't return a sequence, it returns an object from which a sequence can be extracted.  To demonstrate what's happening there, you can use a `for` loop to extract the (number, word) pairs from an `enumerate` generator and print them:

```
for num, word in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 57):
    print 'num is', num, 'and word is', word
```

which shows this:

```
num is 57 and word is a
num is 58 and word is b
num is 59 and word is c
num is 60 and word is d
```

Comment: Thanks for helping